# I tried to create Notes Application using MVVM architecture and Realm database in Android Studio

Tags: android, realm-mobile-platform

Too many arguments for public open fun `getDefaultInstance()`
This is the error I'm getting when i tried to use

```
override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        init(this)
        val configuration = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .name("myNotesapp.realm")
            .build() 
getDefaultInstance(configuration)
```

Comment: Please follow the latest documentation. Here is link that can help you
https://realm.io/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`Realm.getDefaultInstance()` does not accept any parameters.

I think what you want to write is:

```
...
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(configuration)
Realm.getDefaultInstance()
```

Comment: @Charan_pera Great. Please accept my answer to mark it as the correct one.